# There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier browser-wasm

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

1. Blazor Web Assembly Client (.NET 7.0) (almareaEFWeb.Server)
   [image: almareaEFWeb.Server]
2. Blazor Web Assembly Server (.NET 7.0) (almareaEFWeb.Client)
   [image: almareaEFWeb.Client]
3. Entity Framework Core (.NET 7.0) (almareaEFCore)
   [image: almareaEFCore]

Project Web Assembly Client references Entity Framework Core project
Project Web Assembly Server references Entity Framework Core project too

In fact I see yellow warning in packages tree, both in Client and Server projects.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: *AlmereaEFCore* is almost certainly a server side library that is incompatible with WASM projects - as are EFCore libraries.  Why are you trying to use it?

Comment: Necai se I need to use classes defined in almareaEFCore. Only classes definitions. For example to loop through a list in a razor page.

Comment: Do I have to use var?

Comment: If you need some of the functionality then there should be a WAM package as part of `Almerea`.  Without any knowledge of the packages that's the only advice I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if there are some packages which are incompatible with blazor webassembly (check if your third party libraries support blazor webassembly)

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36711